# Environment variable not being read

Tags: ubuntu, environment-variables

I am running Ubuntu 12.04.2 LTS and am having problems with getting a command to execute. I have set up the variable in /etc/environment which looks like this:

```
FEDORA_HOME="/var/lib/fedora"
CATALINA_HOME="/var/lib/tomcat6"
ORACLE_HOME="/usr/lib/oracle/11.2/client64"
JAVA_OPTS="-Xms1024m -Xmx1024m -XX:MaxPermSize=128m - Djavax.net.ssl.trustStore=/usr/local/fedora/truststore -Djavax.net.ssl.trustStorePassword=tomcat"
PATH="/usr/local/sbin:/usr/local/bin:/usr/sbin:/usr/bin:/sbin:/bin:/usr/games:/usr/local/games:$FEDORA_HOME/server:$FEDORA_HOME/client/bin:$ORACLE_HOME:$ORACLE_HOME/bin"
```

The issue is with the $ORACLE_HOME in the PATH variable. I can cd to the correct directory using:

```
cd $ORACLE_HOME/bin
```

But when I try to run sqlplus (the program I am having problems with), the system can't find it. And before anyone asks, yes I have rebooted the system and the file sqlplus does exist in $ORACLE_HOME/bin and is executable by everyone.

This should work, but obviously isn't. Any ideas as to what the issue might be? It is like it doesn't exist in the path although it is clearly there. I can't figure this out. Please help!

Thanks

Comment: You cannot use variables in `/etc/environment`.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The [Ubuntu docs](https://help.ubuntu.com/community/EnvironmentVariables) say that the environment file isn't a script file, so it may not be interpreting your `$ORACLE_HOME` variable the way you hope.  Run `env` to see what your path looks like.  If it isn't what you expect, try hard coding the full path in `/etc/environment` and see if that helps.

Comment: Hard coding the path worked! Thanks. I thought you could put in variable names into the path as I have seen numerous how to manuals that say to do that.

Comment: If you edit your `~/.profile` instead of your `etc/environment`, then you can use variables. However, the path will only be set for your user. If this answer helped you, please consider accepting it.

Answer (score 0):

There are two probable reasons:
1) $PATH isn't set
2) There's conflicting `sqlplus` earlier in the PATH.

To make sure path is set, run `echo $PATH` from console. It should print `/usr/lib/oracle/11.2/client64` among other paths.

Also I recommend to put `$ORACLE_HOME:$ORACLE_HOME/bin` before other paths.

If nothing works, make sure `sqlplus` is directly runnable:
`cd /usr/lib/oracle/11.2/client64`
`./sqlplus`
Maybe it's a script pointing to non-existent shell?